# The identity $\Bbb R^m\times\{0\}^{n-m}=\Bbb R^m$ for $n=m$ can be justified formally?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have the expression $\Bbb R^m\times\{0\}^{n-m}$ what make sense whenever $n>m$. However I want to know if the following identity $\Bbb R^m\times\{0\}^0=\Bbb R^m$ have some formal justification or, by the contrary, it is meaningless without a prior convention about it meaning.

In other words: it is meaningful to talk about the zero power of a set?

Comment: The definition of $X^0$ is the set of functions from $0$ to $X$. Set-theoretically, $0 = \varnothing$ and so you get the set of functions from the empty set to $X$. There is only one such function: the empty function. So $X^0 = \{\varnothing\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to expand a little on my comment.

The idea of strict identity is often a little much to ask for in mathematics. You might know that out of the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ you can construct the integers $\mathbb{Z}$, and out of these the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$, and out of these the reals $\mathbb{R}$. We also think we know that $$\mathbb{N}\subset \mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{R}.$$
However, the obvious constructions I know of the above actually end up with those subset claims being false! For instance, you define $\mathbb{Q}$ as the field of fractions of $\mathbb{Z}$, i.e., an element of $\mathbb{Q}$ is an equivalence class of pairs of members of $\mathbb{Z}$, and so, say $2/1$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ is not the same object as $2\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Why is this not a problem? Well, because we usually only care about *structural features* of objects rather than precisely what objects are being used. This is why we are so concerned with isomorphism is mathematics: It really doesn't matter what your object is made from as long as it exhibits the structural features you care about.

As for your question. Set-theoretically $(X\times X)\times X$ is not actually equal to $X\times(X\times X)$, but there is a natural bijection between the two of them $((x,y),z)\mapsto (x,(y,z))$. So, if $X=\mathbb{R}$ and you care about the vector-space structure on $\mathbb{R}^3$ it doesn't really matter whether your product is left or right associative: you get isomorphic structures out.

Similarly $\mathbb{R}^m \times \{0\}^0 = \mathbb{R}^m \times \{\emptyset\}$, so an element of this product is a pair: the first coordinate is an element of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and the second is the empty set. Consequently, it is likely not the case that $\mathbb{R}^m \times \{0\}^0 = \mathbb{R}^m$, but they exhibit a lot of the same structure. They are both normed vector spaces which are isomorphic etc etc.

Does this clear it up?